# Use Javascript to list all Twilio Messages

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twilio

I am using the Twilio Node.js documentation here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters

I am simply trying to list all of the messages in the message log for an account. Following the example here:

```js
var accountSid = 'your_sid';
var authToken = "your_auth_token";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.list(function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
    });
});
```

**Instead I get an error back:**

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/app.js:9
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/app.js:9:18
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:1547:13
    at Promise_done_fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:835:31)
    at Fulfilled_dispatch [as dispatch] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:1229:9)
    at Pending_become_eachMessage_task (/home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:1369:30)
    at RawTask.call (/home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/node_modules/asap/asap.js:40:19)
    at flush (/home/ubuntu/workspace/twilio/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Note sure why it is not finding anything. I would simply like to print all messages in the message logs or from a specific phone number.

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking under the wrong key? Log out all of data.

Comment: I get the same error when I `console.log(data)`

Comment: Always check your err variable to make sure your request didnt cause an error.

Comment: err variable returned 'null'

Comment: just delete the forEach loop now, and only put `console.log(data)`

Comment: data[0] returns this:


`MessageInstance {
  _version: 
   V2010 {
     _domain: 
      Api {
        twilio: [Object],
        baseUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com',
        _v2010: [Circular] },
     _version: '2010-04-01',
     _accounts: undefined,
     _account: 
      AccountContext {
        _version: [Circular],
    } },
  accountSid: 'redacted',
  apiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  body: 'Submitted!',
from: '+1555555555',
to: '+1555555555',`

Comment: cant figure out how to access each message instance according to properties such as from, to, date, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Twilio's documentation is no longer accurate for NodeJS, the correct way to pull up list of all messages is through the following:

```js
client.messages.list(function(err, data) {

    //notice we have removed 'messages'
    data.forEach(function(message){
        console.log(message.body);
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We [recently released version 3 of our Node library](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/next-generation-node-helper-library-release.html). I believe you are still looking at the documentation for version 2. You can change this in the Twilio documentation by checking the top right of the code samples and selecting 3.x instead of 2.x.

The [up to date documentation for version 3](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message?code-sample=code-list-all-messages&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x) suggests you use code like this:

```
client.messages.each((message) => console.log(message.body));
```

Let me know if that helps at all.